# sort by numeric string using _.sortByOrder lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am trying to *sort numeric string* using `sortbyorder` function of `lodash`.

Function should work as normal on *string only fields* but should sort *in numeric order* in case of numeral string.

Sample array object is as follows:

```js
[{
  "timeInProcessing": "20 min",
  "timeInManual": "8 min",
  "taskID": "653452",
  "reasonType": "Customer Request",
  "assignedStatus": "Robinson, Edwin",
  "virtualMachine": "[machine name]",
  "lastAction": "1st processing fail",
  "region": "EU",
  "project": "Demo Chue STAGE Media Extracts 04",
  "fileName": "Depósito à Prazo BC - BI de Abril a 08 JUN 2016.xlsx",
  "index": "1.0",
  "fileRoom": "NRP TriPost",
  "fileType": "xlsx",
  "fileSize": "22.49 MB",
  "processedBy": "n/a",
  "uploadedBy": "Johnson III, Chadwick",
  "node": "SPWD6PDGDS001"
}, {
  "timeInProcessing": "15 min",
  "timeInManual": "7 min",
  "taskID": "765435",
  "reasonType": "Multiple Attachments",
  "assignedStatus": "Robinson, Edwin",
  "virtualMachine": "[machine name]",
  "lastAction": "2nd processing fail",
  "region": "EU",
  "project": "Blue Thunder",
  "fileName": "lorem_ipsum_dolor.msg",
  "index": "1.1",
  "fileRoom": "North America",
  "fileType": "msg",
  "fileSize": "0.51 MB",
  "processedBy": "Chandwik, Eric",
  "uploadedBy": "Williamson, Lucinda",
  "node": "SPWD6PDGDS002"
}, {
  "timeInProcessing": "10 min",
  "timeInManual": "n/a",
  "taskID": "765436",
  "reasonType": "Customer Request",
  "assignedStatus": "Unassigned",
  "virtualMachine": "n/a",
  "lastAction": "[TBD]",
  "region": "AP",
  "project": "Hercules",
  "fileName": "lorem_ipsum_dolor.msg",
  "index": "1.1.1",
  "fileRoom": "STAGING-Enterprise HR",
  "fileType": "msg",
  "fileSize": "0.01 MB",
  "processedBy": "Holland, Roberta",
  "uploadedBy": "Trisko, Dora",
  "node": "SPWD6PDGDS005"
}, ]
```

the field on which I am trying to sort is `timeInProcessing`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use a sort callback. It takes a key and returns either the numerical value or the original value, if the value would be `NaN`.

```
function byKey(key) {
    return function (o) {
        var v = parseInt(o[key], 10);
        return isNaN(v) ? o[key] : v;
    };
}
```

With lodash 4.17.2 [`_.sortBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#sortBy):

```js
function byKey(key) {
    return function (o) {
        var v = parseInt(o[key], 10);
        return isNaN(v) ? o[key] : v;
    };
}

var data = [{ timeInProcessing: "20 min", timeInManual: "8 min", taskID: "653452" }, { timeInProcessing: "15 min", timeInManual: "7 min", taskID: "765435" }, { timeInProcessing: "10 min", timeInManual: "n/a", "taskID": "765436" }, { timeInProcessing: "min", timeInManual: "n/a", "taskID": "7654XX" }, { timeInProcessing: "abc", timeInManual: "n/a", "taskID": "7654YY" }],
    sorted = _.sortBy(data, byKey('timeInProcessing'));

console.log(sorted);
_.reverse(sorted);
console.log(sorted);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

With lodash 3.10.1 [`_.sortByOrder`](https://lodash.com/docs/3.10.1#sortByOrder):

```js
function byKey(key) {
    return function (o) {
        var v = parseInt(o[key], 10);
        return isNaN(v) ? o[key] : v;
    };
}

var data = [{ timeInProcessing: "20 min", timeInManual: "8 min", taskID: "653452" }, { timeInProcessing: "15 min", timeInManual: "7 min", taskID: "765435" }, { timeInProcessing: "10 min", timeInManual: "n/a", "taskID": "765436" }, { timeInProcessing: "min", timeInManual: "n/a", "taskID": "7654XX" }, { timeInProcessing: "abc", timeInManual: "n/a", "taskID": "7654YY" }],
    sorted = _.sortByOrder(data, byKey('timeInProcessing'), ['asc']);

console.log(sorted);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: can you give an example, how to use this callback in sortByOrder?

Comment: I need to specify the order as well

Comment: @SahilAgarwal for descending order use [`_.reverse`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#reverse)

Comment: @SahilAgarwal an extension of Nina's `sortByOrder` approach. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/zxabbwxk/). Credits to Nina only.

Comment: @Nina, how can I pass another argument of field name by which sorting needs to be done to timeInProcessing function

Comment: do you like to sort by two properties, then you can wrap the functions in an array and hand it over as the second parameter of the underscore sort function, as the specification of underscore describes.

Comment: @NinaScholz I just need to sort by single field but it will be dynamic

Answer (score 0):

I have added a property in your object `sortKey`. This is to hold numeric value for `timeInProcessing`. This will allow you to sort using numeric value.

Also in the following sample, I sorting using `uploadedBy` first and then parsed value to depict sorting on more than 1 key

```js
var data=[{timeInProcessing:"20 min",timeInManual:"8 min",taskID:"653452",reasonType:"Customer Request",assignedStatus:"Robinson, Edwin",virtualMachine:"[machine name]",lastAction:"1st processing fail",region:"EU",project:"Demo Chue STAGE Media Extracts 04",fileName:"Depósito à Prazo BC - BI de Abril a 08 JUN 2016.xlsx",index:"1.0",fileRoom:"NRP TriPost",fileType:"xlsx",fileSize:"22.49 MB",processedBy:"n/a",uploadedBy:"Johnson III, Chadwick",node:"SPWD6PDGDS001"},{timeInProcessing:"15 min",timeInManual:"7 min",taskID:"765435",reasonType:"Multiple Attachments",assignedStatus:"Robinson, Edwin",virtualMachine:"[machine name]",lastAction:"2nd processing fail",region:"EU",project:"Blue Thunder",fileName:"lorem_ipsum_dolor.msg",index:"1.1",fileRoom:"North America",fileType:"msg",fileSize:"0.51 MB",processedBy:"Chandwik, Eric",uploadedBy:"Williamson, Lucinda",node:"SPWD6PDGDS002"},{timeInProcessing:"10 min",timeInManual:"n/a",taskID:"765436",reasonType:"Customer Request",assignedStatus:"Unassigned",virtualMachine:"n/a",lastAction:"[TBD]",region:"AP",project:"Hercules",fileName:"lorem_ipsum_dolor.msg",index:"1.1.1",fileRoom:"STAGING-Enterprise HR",fileType:"msg",fileSize:"0.01 MB",processedBy:"Holland, Roberta",uploadedBy:"Trisko, Dora",node:"SPWD6PDGDS005"}];

var sortedOrder = _.sortByOrder(_.map(data, function(o) {
  o["timeInProcessing_num"] = parseInt(o.timeInProcessing, 10);
  return o;
}), ["uploadedBy", "timeInProcessing_num"])
console.log(sortedOrder)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: just a hint, please use `parseInt` with base.

Comment: @NinaScholz Done. :-)